# How should maximum likelihood classifier be implemented in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am on a path of learning Matlab as I was researching I got stuck on a topic of maximum likelihood classification of the image. I know that covariance and variance needs to be calculated in order to implement it. So how should one code maximum likelihood classifier?

Thanks for reading and helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try the mle() function (Maximum likelihood estimation)